# run start:dev failes Unexpected identifier in concurrently

Tags: node.js

I'm rather new to the nodejs world and having trouble with some basics ,

when I do npm install it shows a few warn messages but complete it .

when I do npm build it works fine

but when I do run start:dev it crashes with this error message :

```
concurrently\bin\concurrently.js:140
let lastColor;
^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:dev"
npm ERR! node v0.12.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! izi-backend@0.0.1 start:dev: `concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json" `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the izi-backend@0.0.1 start:dev script 'concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json" '.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the izi-backend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json"
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls izi-backend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\dev\iziMobile\izi-server\npm-debug.log
```

where npm run start:dev is defined as :

```
"start:dev": "concurrently --handle-input \"wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon\" \"tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json\" "
```

also printing out npm-debug.log:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe',
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'run',
>   1 verbose cli   'start:dev' ]
>   2 info using npm@2.7.4
>   3 info using node@v0.12.2
>   4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
>   5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart:dev', 'start:dev', 'poststart:dev' ]
>   6 info prestart:dev izi-backend@0.0.1
>   7 info start:dev izi-backend@0.0.1
>   8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>   9 info izi-backend@0.0.1 Failed to exec start:dev script
>   10 verbose stack Error: izi-backend@0.0.1 start:dev: `concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json"`
>   10 verbose stack Exit status 1
>   10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
>   10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
>   10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:14:12)
>   10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>   10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
>   10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
>   11 verbose pkgid izi-backend@0.0.1
>   12 verbose cwd C:\dev\iziMobile\izi-server
>   13 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   14 error argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "start:dev"
>   15 error node v0.12.2
>   16 error npm  v2.7.4
>   17 error code ELIFECYCLE
>   18 error izi-backend@0.0.1 start:dev: `concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json"`
>   18 error Exit status 1
>   19 error Failed at the izi-backend@0.0.1 start:dev script 'concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json" '.
>   19 error This is most likely a problem with the izi-backend package,
>   19 error not with npm itself.
>   19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   19 error     concurrently --handle-input "wait-on dist/main.js && nodemon" "tsc -w -p tsconfig.build.json"
>   19 error You can get their info via:
>   19 error     npm owner ls izi-backend
>   19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>   20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]<

Concurrently is a package I take in packages.json so I doubt there is really an error there...

Am I missing anything ? 
Any help will do at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node v0.12.2 does not support the `let` declarations.

See [here](https://node.green/#let) for the full version support matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You are using node version `v0.12.2`. `let` syntax is not supported.

From [`node.green`](https://node.green/#ES2015-bindings-let) you can see that `let` is supported from **Node v6.4.x**